# How can I force .htaccess to ignore a folder?

Tags: .htaccess

I was using the search function, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I have the following .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(api) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /tsi/index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /tsi/index.php

<FilesMatch ".*\.(php|tpl)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files "index.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "hashgenerator\.(php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "xmlgenerator\.(php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "api\.(php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I have a folder named "api" which I want to be ignored by .htaccess.